# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous in laravel

Tags: laravel

my controller code is

```
$data = DB::table('ride')
                    ->leftJoin('driver','ride.driver_id','=','driver.id')
                    ->select([
                    DB::raw('driver.name as driver_name'),
                    DB::raw('monthname(ride.created_at) as month'),
                    DB::raw('year(ride.created_at) as year'),
                ])
                ->where("driver.users_id", $users_id)
                ->groupBy(['year', 'month','driver_id'])
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

but it show me Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous although i already mention 'ride.created_at'

model

```
protected $table = "ride";

public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable =[
        'status',
        'driver_id',

];
```

Comment: What does your ride model look like? Are you able to show the migration for it?

Comment: check updated question

Comment: @afra-janjua I think it'll be better that show the migration file not model.

Comment: ok i added both migration and model

Answer (score 0):

I just setup new project to test this.
There is no specification about `driver` table, just added what can be inferred.
In my envirnoment(**laravel7 + mysql**), it just complained about `driver.name` is not in group by.
After adding `driver_name` field to group by, it works.

I think it's not the problem of query above. Or you missed something in the question.

Because you are not use `created_at` in `where` clause.

[image]

- `ride` migration

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('driver_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('driver_id')->references('id')->on('driver');
$table->timestamps();
```

- `driver` migration

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->integer('users_id');
$table->timestamps();
```

- directly call in the `web` routes

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $users_id = 1;

    $data = DB::table('ride')
        ->leftJoin('driver', 'ride.driver_id', '=', 'driver.id')
        ->select([
            DB::raw('driver.name as driver_name'),
            DB::raw('monthname(ride.created_at) as month'),
            DB::raw('year(ride.created_at) as year'),
        ])
        ->where("driver.users_id", $users_id)
        ->groupBy(['year', 'month', 'driver_id', 'driver_name'])
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    dd($data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be included in your 'Ride' model.

public $timestamps = false;